# Chi-square distribution

Tags: r, statistics, probability, chi-squared

I want to check this probability in R:

`P(X>logY)` where X is a chi-square variable with df=2 and Y is probability from a data.

How can I do this? I tried `pchisq(log(Y), 2)` but I'm not sure if it is correct.

Comment: if you mean the probability of obtaining X > logY, then it should be pchisq(log(Y),2,lower.tail=FALSE). pchisq gives the cumulative

Comment: If `Y` is a probability, `log(Y)` is negative or zero, so `P(X > log(Y))` is 1.

Comment: Oh yeah @user2554330 you are right, I missed the part about Y is probability. Yeah pnina, it's weird you are calculating this